# Insert text at specific line number

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I'm working on a bash script that will split the contents of a text document depending on the data in the line.

If the contents of the original file were along the lines of

```
01 line
01 line
02 line
02 line
```

How can I insert into line 3 of this file using bash to result in

```
01 line
01 line
text to insert
02 line
02 line
```

I'm hoping to do this using a heredoc or something similar in my script

```
#!/bin/bash

vim -e -s ./file.txt <<- HEREDOC
    :3 | startinsert | "text to insert\n"
    :update
    :quit
HEREDOC
```

The above doesn't work of course but any recommendations that I could implement into this bash script?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537490/insert-a-line-at-specific-line-number-with-sed-or-awk

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the POSIX tool `ex` by line number:

```
ex a.txt <<eof
3 insert
Sunday
.
xit
eof
```

Or string match:

```
ex a.txt <<eof
/Monday/ insert
Sunday
.
xit
eof
```

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html

Answer (score 15):

`sed` would be a traditional choice (GNU sed probably has an easier form than this).

```
$ cat input
01 line
01 line
02 line
02 line
$ sed '2a\
text to insert
' < input
01 line
01 line
text to insert
02 line
02 line
$
```

Or, being extremely traditional, `ed` (bonus! in-place edit without the unportable `sed -i` form).

```
$ (echo 2; echo a; echo text to insert; echo .; echo wq) | ed input
32
01 line
47
$ cat input
01 line
01 line
text to insert
02 line
02 line
$
```

(This has nothing to do with `bash`.)

Comment: added bonux replace `echo text to insert` by `cat file-to-insert.txt`

Comment: At least with bash, instead of all those `echo`s, you could use `printf '%s\n' 2 a 'text to insert' . wq`

Answer (score 13):

```
$ awk 'NR==3{print "text to insert"}1' a.txt
01 line
01 line
text to insert
02 line
02 line
```

Comment: can be used as `awk -i inplace '...'` for a one-line equivalent of the `sed -i` solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/

Answer (score 9):

How about something like:

```
head -n 2 ./file.txt > newfile.txt
echo "text to insert" >> newfile.txt
tail -n +3 ./file.txt >> newfile.txt
mv newfile.txt file.txt
```

Comment: Strange but interesting idea +1

Comment: head -n 5 ./pom.xml > pomnew.xml
echo "<packaging>war</packaging>" >> pomnew.xml
tail -n +6 ./pom.xml >> pomnew.xml
mv pomnew.xml pom.xml

Comment: You may compact this like this: `(head -2 file.txt; echo row three ; tail -3 file.txt) > newfile.txt`  (using Gnu Linux tools).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Your original file

```
$ cat <<'EOF' > file.txt
01 line
01 line
02 line
02 line
EOF
```

insert into line 3 using a heredoc.

```
$ cat <<'EOF' | sed -i "3r /dev/stdin" file.txt
text to insert
EOF
```

you get this result

```
$ cat file.txt
01 line
01 line
text to insert
02 line
02 line
```

**UPDATED**: Following the comment of @Kusalananda

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).  Also note that the user gives a specific example use case in their question. It would benefit your answer (and your duplicated answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/736604/116858)) to actually use the user's sample documents.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Thanks for your comment. I've updated my answer.