# Insert command line information into the specified line of the file

Tags: text-processing, sed

source file:

```
$cat test.file 
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

I want to insert `echo test> /var/tmp/file` into the second line, and the desired result is like this:

```
$ cat test.file 
aaa
echo test > /var/tmp/file
bbb
ccc
```

I tried the following, but failed :(

```
$ sed -i "2 s/^/echo test > /var/tmp/file\n/" test.file                                          
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unknown option to `s'

$ sed -i "2 s/^/"echo test > /var/tmp/file"\n/" test.file 
-bash: /var/tmp/file\n/: Is a directory
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert text at specific line number](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271475/insert-text-at-specific-line-number)

Comment: The actual error is explained in [How to replace a string with a string containing slash with sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39800/how-to-replace-a-string-with-a-string-containing-slash-with-sed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
sed '2i echo test > /var/tmp/file' infile
```

`2i` says insert text at second line.

---

your own solution also should work, but since there are `/` in your text that you want add and `sed` itself also using `/` character for substitution character, so they will conflict with each other.

You have two ways to fix this:

1. change sed `/` substitution character to something else that do not exists in your input file:

   ```
   sed '2 s:^:echo test > /var/tmp/file\n:' infile
   ```
2. escape all `/` characters from your text you are going to add to your file.

   ```
   sed '2 s/^/echo test > \/var\/tmp\/file\n/' infile
   ```

add `-i` switch for in-place replace to your command when you were happy with the result.

```
sed -i '2 s/^/echo test > \/var\/tmp\/file\n/' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

With this there's no need to escape any characters. The `r` read file command will place the contents of the file after the specified line number, in this case after
Iine #1.

```
$ echo 'echo test > /var/tmp/file' \
| sed -i '1r /dev/stdin' file
```